# how to include port in nodejs url parse

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, url

Well... I have a very simple use case.

I have two strings:

```
var a = 'localhost:3000',
    b = '/whatever/; // this can also be whatever/ or /whatever
```

I need to parse

```
url.parse(a, b); // so that it takes care of dealing with slashes
```

But I get

```
localhost:/whatever/ instead of localhost:3000/whatever/
```

Any pointers?

Thanks!

Comment: `url.parse` takes only one string parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you compare the two following calls you'll see that adding a protocol to the front of the string makes a big difference:

```
> url.parse('http://localhost:3000', '/whatever/')
{ protocol: 'http:',
  slashes: true,
  auth: null,
  host: 'localhost:3000',
  port: '3000',
  hostname: 'localhost',
  hash: null,
  search: '',
  query: {},
  pathname: '/',
  path: '/',
  href: 'http://localhost:3000/' }
>
```

Without

```
> url.parse('localhost:3000', '/whatever/')
{ protocol: 'localhost:',
  slashes: null,
  auth: null,
  host: '3000',
  port: null,
  hostname: '3000',
  hash: null,
  search: '',
  query: {},
  pathname: null,
  path: null,
  href: 'localhost:3000' }
>
```

What you are probably looking for adds the protocol and then uses `+` instead of `,`:

```
> url.parse('http://localhost:3000' + '/whatever/')
{ protocol: 'http:',
  slashes: true,
  auth: null,
  host: 'localhost:3000',
  port: '3000',
  hostname: 'localhost',
  hash: null,
  search: null,
  query: null,
  pathname: '/whatever/',
  path: '/whatever/',
  href: 'http://localhost:3000/whatever/' }
>
```

Answer (score 0):

A option ca be doing a [normalize path](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_normalize_p) with:

```
path.normalize('/foo/bar//baz/asdf');  // the path  here

// returns  '/foo/bar/baz/asdf'
```

then:

```
var cleanUrl = 'localhost:3000' + path.normalize(yourpath);
```